# How to calculate the number of messages sent in a distributed system?

Tags: networking, process, distributed, rounding

Suppose we have n processes forming a general network. We don't know which are connected together, but we know the number of the processes (n).If at each round, a process sends a message to all processes it is connected to, receives 1 message from each of them, and the program executes for r rounds, is there a way to find how many messages have been sent during the program execution?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, where are you stuck?

Comment: Never denied that it's homework..And i don't understand the purpose of the comment.I don't seek just an answer, i seek an explanation. In the problem, i mean its not possible to find the exact number of sent messages, instead we got to find it like an order of the number, eg O(n^2)

Comment: _is there a way to find how many messages have been sent during the program execution?_ **Yes.**

Answer (score 2):

As you have pointed out, without the exact network structure it is impossible to put a specific value on the number of messages sent. Instead, we can look at its Big-O value.

Now just to be clear what we mean by Big-O:

- Big-O refers to the **upper bound** (ie. the worst possible case) complexity
- It is possible (and quite likely in real systems) that the actual value will be less
- Without some function that describes the average case (eg. each process is connected to, on average `N / 2` other processes) we must assume the worst case
- By "worst case" for this problem we mean the maximum number of messages are sent

So let us assume the worst case, in which each process is connected to `N - 1` other processes.

Let us also define some variables:

- `S` := the set of processes
- `N` := the number of processes in `S`

We can represent the set `S` as a complete (every node connects to every other node), undirected graph in which each node in the graph corresponds to a process and each edge in the graph corresponds to 2 messages sent (1 outgoing transmission and one reply).

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph), we see that the number of edges in a complete graph is `(N(N-1))/2`

So in the worst case, the number of messages sent is `N(N-1)`, or `N^2 - N`.

Now because we are dealing with Big-O notation, we are interested in how this value grows as a function of `N`.

By the triangle inequality, we can see that `O(N^2 - N)` is an element of `O(N^2)`.

So the number of messages sent grows as `N^2` in the worst case.

---

It is also possible to arrive at this result using an adjacency matrix, that is an `N x N` matrix where a `1` in the `(i, j)`th element refers to an edge from node `i` to node `j`.

Because in the original problem each process sends a single message to all connected processes, who respond with a single message, we can see that for every pair `(i, j)` and `(j, i)` there will be an edge (one representing an outgoing message, one a reply). The exception to this will be pairs where `i = j`, ie. we a process doesn't send itself a message.
So the matrix will be completely filled with `1`s with the exception of the diagonal.

```
0 1 1 1
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0
```

*Above: the adjacency matrix for N = 4*.

So we first want to determine a formula for the total number of messages sent as a function of the number of nodes.

By the area of a rectangle we can see that the number of `1`s in the matrix (ignoring the diagonal) would be `N x N = N^2`.
Now we must consider the diagonal. The number of pairs `(x, x)` that can exist is given by the function `f(i) where Z(N) -> Z(N) x Z(N) : f(i) = (i, i)` -- this means that there will be exactly N distinct solutions to this function.

So the overall result is that we have `N^2 - N` messages when the diagonal is considered.

Now, we use the same Big-O reasoning from above to arrive at the same conclusion, the number of messages grows in the worst case as `O(N^2)`.

---

So, now you need only take into consideration the number of rounds that have occured, leaving you with O(RN^2).

Of course now you must consider whether you really do have the worst case ...